# how to set "Re-deploy already installed packages" as default in Octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy

How do i change a default settings for Re-deploy already installed packages?
[image]

I want this to always be selected when deploying.

i have tried using

`OctopusForcePackageRedeployment = true`

and

`Octopus.Deployment.ForcePackageDownload = true`

they don't work.

Comment: Are you setting re-deploy from the release page? Or the settings page on the project itself?

Comment: this is from release deployment page, basically when I am deploying the release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments, you're setting this per-release. To change the default for the project the releases are created in, go to Settings on the project itself

[image]

If you change the default on the Project, any Release created within the Project will inherit that setting.